# Spark Scala Dataframe миллисекунды в формат даты типа 2021-05-01 12:00:00

Tags: scala, apache-spark

наверное вопрос не из сложных, но я так и не смогла найти нужную информацию в интернете. Есть понятные для меня скрипты как перевести формат времени в миллисекунды, а именно миллисекунды в формат 2019-07-27 00:00:00? у меня есть датафрейм, по сути я бы хотела уже в нем изменить формат: Time interval 1383346800000 в формат даты  2021-05-01 12:00:00. Ну или может быть есть варианты при создании схемы и загрузки df это сделать. Буду безмерно благодарна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь поможет функция `from_unixtime` (из `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`):

```scala
df.withColumn("date", from_unixtime(col("milliseconds") / 1000)).show()
```

Comment: Ураа! это сработало, благодарю! от души, только маленький вопрос, у меня есть готовый df, после исполнения кода добивался столбец, понятно, что с миллисекундами - могу потом удалить, а можно более изящно сделать, чтобы просто замена произошла?

Comment: Можно просто использовать `withColumn` с указанием того же самого имени столбца, в котором до этого хранились миллисекунды

Comment: как оказывается просто! Благодарю Вас!